# How to safely store infected PDF file that I have created?

Tags: malware, virus, pdf

I have two computers, computer A and computer B.

With computer B I created an infected PDF file using setoolkit following [this youtube toturial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeZWuo6adWs). The file is on a VM right now.

On computer A I have a file scanner software that scan files and tells if they are infected or not. I want to test the scanner therefore by scanning the infected PDF that I have created,

I plan to send the infected file from computer B to my email and then to open the mail from computer A. Is it safe to store the infected file on computer A because I want to scan it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case (pdf file) you can safely store that file wherever you want as long as it is not read by any program affected by the bug your pdf file explotes. If instead of a pdf file it is an executable one then you can also store it wherever you want as long as you (or any other automated mechanism) don't execute it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I don't have enough reputation to up vote

Answer (score 0):

Have you crafted a pdf file that infects a machine simply by storing it? I don't think so. 
 
The file infects a system when it **is executed**. 
It is unsafe to a) store the file on computer A and b) execute it.

 It is safe to store the file on computer A. 
 
Here is another question. Is computer B infected now?

Comment: You don't need to "execute" a file to infect a system. If that file is read by a buggy program and the file is created in a way that allows exploiting that program's bug then you have infected the system with a non executable file.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I don't have enough reputation to up vote